# Wrapping a third party lib

Tags: reactjs

Let me simplify the problem to the following **artificial** case:

Child is a child component of Parent and used like this:

```
<Parent>
   <Child parentColor=32/>
</Parent>
```

Now, Child needs to set the color of Parent.

Basically, where/how should I handle cases where a Child needs to access the DOM element of a Parent.

Comment: Making use of a global application state may be one solution. Something like Redux or a similar store in which some action can alter the state of `Parent`.

Answer (score 0):

Data flow in react is a unidirectional flow, from Parent to Child.
Children will usually pass data back to the parent with callbacks (or event handlers).

A Child component should know nothing about its parents nor siblings, It should only care about itself and in some cases its own children.

For example, a Child that has a text input and a button. it will manage the input's value in its own state and will pass back the value of its input via the `onClick` event of its button.

What will the parent do with this value? The Child component doesn't really care. a handler event is passed to it via the parent and the Child will invoke it with the value from its state. That's all the Child needs to know about.

Here is a small running example:

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };
  }

  onChange = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({ value: target.value });
  }

  onSubmit = () => {
    const { onSubmit } = this.props;
    onSubmit(this.state.value);
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          placeholder="type a color"
          type="text"
          value={value}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Change Color</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: 'green'
    };
  }

  onColorChange = color => this.setState({ color });

  render() {
    const { color } = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>
        <Child onSubmit={this.onColorChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I wrote that it’s an artificial case. The reason is that the third party library has it’s own object model outside of the DOM.

Comment: the third party component is the child component in your case i assume. then if it has an api for providing data via callbacks, where is  the issue here? perhaps provide the real use case and the third party component that you are using?